# Copy mp3 files from Isolated storage to media library in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

I am able to store media files into the Isolated Storage and able to retrieve the same. Now what I want is to play that file in music player in phone, but music player says "no music found". How can i show my downloaded mp3 files in isolated storage to the media library? I am using this code to download the mp3 file. Is there any way to download the file to the readable storage like (phone memory/ internal storage / memory card)???

```
  void imgDown_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        ToastPrompt toast = new ToastPrompt();
        toast.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        toast.FontSize = 20;
        toast.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        toast.Message = "Please wait";
        toast.Show();
try
        {
            //Create a webclient that'll handle your download
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            //Run function when resource-read (OpenRead) operation is completed
            client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;
            //Start download / open stream
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(streamUrl));
}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            toast.Message = "Downloading error";
            toast.Show();
        }
    }
    async void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, 
OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToastPrompt toast = new ToastPrompt();
        toast.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        toast.FontSize = 20;
        toast.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        toast.Message = "Downloading starts";
        toast.Show();
        try
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
            //Store bytes in buffer, so it can be saved later on
            await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


            using (IsolatedStorageFile file 
            IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {

                //Create file
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream =
file.OpenFile(titleUrl+".mp3", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    //Write content stream to file
                    await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
               // StorageFolder local = 
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                //StorageFile storedFile = await local.GetFileAsync(titleUrl + 
".mp3");

                toast.Message = "Downloading complete";
                toast.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            toast.Message = "We could not finish your download. Error ";
            toast.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Once you get the *StorageFile storedFile*, have you tried just to copy it to MusicFolder: `await storedFile.CopyAsync(KnownFolders.MusicLibrary);`? Of course for this you will need *Music Library* capability in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the `MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong` method (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.PhoneExtensions.medialibraryextensions.savesong(v=xnagamestudio.42).aspx)

You'll need to add the `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO` capability to your app, and get a URI for the file on the Isolated Storage to pass to that method.

There's some more information on [Data for Windows Phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx) on MSDN.